# Empathy chat notification

Tags: empathy, notification

I am using Empathy IM Client for my google hosted mail domain on 9.04, 9.10, 10.04 desktops. I could able to chat from the google mail chat to Empathy and I have set empathy notification to get notified when a message is received and it pops up. Whenever it pops up, it show the complete message of the sender which I don't like/want the message to be revealed to everyone whoever looks at my desktop.

Is there anything I could do so that the actual message is not shown whenever empathy pops up instead showing any message something similar to `"You have got a new message"`?.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't. In the Preferences window you can only disable/enable the visual notifications. If you don't like/want the message to be revealed to everyone looks at your desktop, you can disable the visual notifications and pay attention only to the Indicator Message (the envelope  on the top panel).

Comment: hmmm..... can't have any third party notifier for Empathy chat, isn't there any script for this?.

Comment: well, AFAIK there are no third party notifier. By the way, there could be a solution: you could disable the Empathy notification system and write a script (python??) that listens on DBUS for Empathy messages, and then emits a OSD Notification of your choice.

Comment: I've no much knowledge of scripting. we'll be interacting one another over LAN and WAN everyday and I have to set this up on all the systems. I can't disable notification as it is needed for everyone and everybody complains that their messages are visible to others